# Looking for Dropdown (maybe a Framework)

Tags: angular, select, frameworks, dropdown

I am looking for an Dropdown, which looks like the following:

[image]

Does someone have an suggestions?
(For example Angular Material does not seem to work for my requirements)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to find the specific framework, where dropdown looks exactly like on your screenshot? or you want to find a framework just with the functionality of multi-select in dropdown?

Comment: You can use this npm library for using the above method

    https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: @ Michał Tkaczyk I am looking for a framework which exactly looks like this dropdown.
So to be clear - it should have checkboxes whitin the dropdown and the items should be counted.
The title on the top corner is not a must have, but  it would be easier if it was there too.

Comment: @ Miyas Mohammed this looks good..but can I optimize this dropdown so that the selected values are counted instead of the displayed buttons?

Comment: this does not have a checkboxes but you archive the final result. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Comment: @hansand thanks this is what I was looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is actually a library and not a framework.

[Check out this multiselect npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)

Following is the settings object which you can pass in to this component to customize the behavior of your multiselect dropdown.

```
    IDropdownSettings {

singleSelection?: boolean;
idField?: string;
textField?: string;
disabledField?: string;
enableCheckAll?: boolean;
selectAllText?: string;
unSelectAllText?: string;
allowSearchFilter?: boolean;
clearSearchFilter?: boolean;
maxHeight?: number;
itemsShowLimit?: number;
limitSelection?: number;
searchPlaceholderText?: string;
noDataAvailablePlaceholderText?: string;
closeDropDownOnSelection?: boolean;
showSelectedItemsAtTop?: boolean;
defaultOpen?: boolean;
allowRemoteDataSearch?: boolean;
```

}

Comment: How to capture the text entered to use allowRemoteDataSearch ?